# Heroku ERROR: Failed parsing composer.lock; it must be non-empty and valid JSON

Tags: php, json, heroku

Currently getting this error and not sure how to fix, I ran composer update but that didn't resolve it.

```
$ git push
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 621 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> PHP app detected

!     ERROR: Failed parsing composer.lock; it must be non-empty and valid JSON.

   Run 'composer update' to have it re-generated or removed by Composer.


!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

To git@heroku.com:foo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:foo.git'
```

Comment: What is in your composer.lock?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. You composer.lock file is either invalid json or an empty file. You should run composer update before committing the lock file to generate a valid file.

Comment: My composer is not empty, I ran it in json lint and it was invalid json. I ran composer update like I stated above, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you paste your `composer.lock` somewhere, e.g. on pastebin or in a gist?

Comment: any resolution to this? getting this with heroku's buildpack on packager.io

Answer (score 3):

I just had exactly the same problem. However after double checking the lock file was valid JSON and was a valid file.

Solution turned out to be updating composer itself "composer self-update" to the latest version then it worked fine