# ERROR: Couldn't parse 'composer.lock'; it must be a valid lock file generated by Composer

Tags: php, git, heroku, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a simple app to Heroku, but keep getting this error message:

```
Alastairs-MacBook-Air:php-getting-started alastair$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Couldn't parse 'composer.lock'; it must be a valid lock
remote:        file generated by Composer. Run 'composer update', add/commit
remote:        the change, then push again.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to arcane-peak-94383.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-peak-94383.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arcane-peak-94383.git'
```

It's this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#push-local-changes).

I've ran composer update multiple times, add/committed the change, and reinstalled composer. All with no luck. The composer.lock file was generated by Composer, as I've regenerated it by running composer update.

Here's my composer.json file:

```
{
 "require" : {
"silex/silex": "^1.3",
"monolog/monolog": "^1.4",
"twig/twig": "^1.8",
"symfony/twig-bridge": "^2",
"alrik11es/cowsayphp": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
"heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
 }
}
```

I know this is a simple solution, but I have been trying to resolve for a couple of hours now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json`?

Comment: Sure - will add into my original post. Thanks.

Comment: Seems OK.. And have you included `composer.lock` file in your commit?

Comment: Pretty sure I have. I haven't `.gitignore` 'd it. Seems to suggest that this is the right thing to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896780/should-composer-lock-be-committed-to-version-control)

Comment: Run `git status` just to check. It's supposed to be added to the repository explicitely.

Comment: Got this:  `git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689081/heroku-error-failed-parsing-composer-lock-it-must-be-non-empty-and-valid-json) that should do it:

Seems that Heroku supports only latest versions of Composer.

`composer self-update` and further `composer update` (+ `git add`, + `git commit`) should fix the issue.